# Python Regex on comma, space

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string `"Dogs,cats"`. If I do `re.split(r'[,]*', 'Dogs,cats')`, then I get `['Dogs', 'cats']`, and this is good, but if I get `'Dogs, cats'`, then I get a list `['Dogs', ' cats']` and this is bad. How to I make my regex pattern match either having a comma with no space or with a space to still give me `['Dogs', 'cats']`?

I tried `re.split(r'[\s,]*', 'Dogs,cats')` and while that works here, it gives an unwanted splitting in the cases where I have a say, `'dogs,cats are Happy'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first case doesn't even need a regex. You can simply do:

```
"Dogs,Cats".split(",")
```

For your 2nd case, you can use:

```
re.split(r',\s*', "Dogs, Cats")
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters. OOPs, mixed up with Java.

Comment: Yea, I used the `split` method previously, but the issue came up of having a space after the `,`, which would mess up the result I wanted.

Comment: @RohitJain Awesome, worked. I'll accept when the ticker lets me. Thanks!